# Material3 DatePicker background color in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I use `DatePicker` from `material3` with custom colors.

I want to change background color of `DatePicker`. As I understand I need to change actually the elevation overlay color of `Surface`. But how I can do it?

Here is my code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF)
@Composable
fun DatePickerPreview() {
    val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState(initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Picker)
    Surface(
        tonalElevation = 6.dp,
        contentColor = AppTheme.colors.textSecondary,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
        ) {
        DatePicker(
            state = datePickerState,
            colors = AppDefaults.datePickerColors(),
            dateValidator = {
                DateTimeUtils.timestampToDate(it)?.isAfter(Date()) == false
            }
        )
    }
}
```

But background color of DatePicker now is the default material neutral color. I want to set my custom blue color for it instead of material purple, but with correctly calculated alpha like in `material3`. [Explanation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#elevation) of material3 `tonalElevation`.

The overlay color comes from the primary color slot but I don't use `MeterialTheme` for my app, instead of this I use the my custom theme

And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: You can change background color of DatePicker by assigning `Modifier.background` to it.  contentColor changes color of arrows. What do you mean by correctly calculated alpha?

Comment: @Thracian Of course, I understand that I can set just the background color through a modifier, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want the color to match the set `tonalElevation` value. Here is the explanation of m3 elevation concept https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#elevation . I update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I solved this by locally using of `MaterialTheme` from `material3` and overriding some colors:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF)
@Composable
fun DatePickerMaterialTheme() {
    val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState(initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Picker)
    val validate: (Long) -> Boolean = remember { { DateTimeUtils.timestampToDate(it)?.isAfter(Date()) == false } }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.copy(
            surface = AppTheme.colors.surface,
            primary = AppTheme.colors.primary,
            onPrimary = AppTheme.colors.onPrimary
        )
    ) {
        Surface(
            tonalElevation = 6.dp,
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge
        ) {
            DatePicker(
                state = datePickerState,
                dateValidator = validate
            )
        }
    }
}
```